# Intersection of line segment with axis-aligned box in C#

Tags: c#, 3d

I'm looking for an algorithm that determines the near and far intersection points between a line segment and an axis-aligned box.

Here is my method definition:

```
public static Point3D[] IntersectionOfLineSegmentWithAxisAlignedBox(
    Point3D rayBegin, Point3D rayEnd, Point3D boxCenter, Size3D boxSize)
```

If the line segment doesn't intersect the box, the method should return an empty `Point3D` array.

From my research so far, I've come across some research papers with highly optimized algorithms, but they all seem to be written in C++ and would require multiple long class files to be converted to C#. For my purposes, something that is reasonably efficient, easy to understand by someone who gets dot products and cross products, and simple/short would be preferred.

Comment: I don't know the algorithm but I think returning `null` is a bit unusual. An empty array is much nicer, it's clear there are no points that intersect (Length = 0), and you won't need to perform null checks in the consuming code.

Comment: Just being picky, but a ray doesn't have an end point - it's infinite in one direction.  A line that has a start and end point is a line segment.

Comment: Good point, @RichK...I corrected my question.

Comment: Good point, @Incredulous Monk, I corrected my question.

Comment: http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/Intersection.html is always a great place to look for this sort of thing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
public static List<Point3D> IntersectionOfLineSegmentWithAxisAlignedBox(
    Point3D segmentBegin, Point3D segmentEnd, Point3D boxCenter, Size3D boxSize)
{
    var beginToEnd = segmentEnd - segmentBegin;
    var minToMax = new Vector3D(boxSize.X, boxSize.Y, boxSize.Z);
    var min = boxCenter - minToMax / 2;
    var max = boxCenter + minToMax / 2;
    var beginToMin = min - segmentBegin;
    var beginToMax = max - segmentBegin;
    var tNear = double.MinValue;
    var tFar = double.MaxValue;
    var intersections = new List<Point3D>();
    foreach (Axis axis in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Axis)))
    {
        if (beginToEnd.GetCoordinate(axis) == 0) // parallel
        {
            if (beginToMin.GetCoordinate(axis) > 0 || beginToMax.GetCoordinate(axis) < 0)
                return intersections; // segment is not between planes
        }
        else
        {
            var t1 = beginToMin.GetCoordinate(axis) / beginToEnd.GetCoordinate(axis);
            var t2 = beginToMax.GetCoordinate(axis) / beginToEnd.GetCoordinate(axis);
            var tMin = Math.Min(t1, t2);
            var tMax = Math.Max(t1, t2);
            if (tMin > tNear) tNear = tMin;
            if (tMax < tFar) tFar = tMax;
            if (tNear > tFar || tFar < 0) return intersections;

        }
    }
    if (tNear >= 0 && tNear <= 1) intersections.Add(segmentBegin + beginToEnd * tNear);
    if (tFar >= 0 && tFar <= 1) intersections.Add(segmentBegin + beginToEnd * tFar);
    return intersections;
}
```

---

```
public enum Axis
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

---

```
public static double GetCoordinate(this Point3D point, Axis axis)
{
    switch (axis)
    {
        case Axis.X:
            return point.X;
        case Axis.Y:
            return point.Y;
        case Axis.Z:
            return point.Z;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

public static double GetCoordinate(this Vector3D vector, Axis axis)
{
    switch (axis)
    {
        case Axis.X:
            return vector.X;
        case Axis.Y:
            return vector.Y;
        case Axis.Z:
            return vector.Z;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: At least a little bit of explanation [here](http://www.garagegames.com/community/blogs/view/309). 

This algorithm calculates the fraction of the line you have to go from the start-point until the intersections. It does this by looking at each axis as a one-dimensional problem, where it finds the proportion of the line, which needs to be added to start, to reach the intersection.

Comment: This could be improved by checking the bounding box first:

 `if (begin>max || end < min) return intersections; // no intersection`

Answer (score 3):

Well, for an axis-aligned box it's pretty simple: you have to find intersection of your ray with 6 planes (defined by the box faces) and then check the points you found against the box vertices coordinates limits.

Answer (score 2):

Optimized version of the answer. There is no reason to do allocations or lookups.

```
public struct Ray3
{
  public Vec3 origin, direction;

        public bool IntersectRayBox(Box3 box, out Vec3 point1, out Vec3 point2)
        {
            var min = (box.center - (box.size / 2)) - origin;
            var max = (box.center + (box.size / 2)) - origin;
            float near = float.MinValue;
            float far = float.MaxValue;

            // X
            float t1 = min.x / direction.x;
            float t2 = max.x / direction.x;
            float tMin = Math.Min(t1, t2);
            float tMax = Math.Max(t1, t2);
            if (tMin > near) near = tMin;
            if (tMax < far) far = tMax;
            if (near > far || far < 0)
            {
                point1 = Vec3.zero;
                point2 = Vec3.zero;
                return false;
            }

            // Y
            t1 = min.y / direction.y;
            t2 = max.y / direction.y;
            tMin = Math.Min(t1, t2);
            tMax = Math.Max(t1, t2);
            if (tMin > near) near = tMin;
            if (tMax < far) far = tMax;
            if (near > far || far < 0)
            {
                point1 = Vec3.zero;
                point2 = Vec3.zero;
                return false;
            }

            // Z
            t1 = min.z / direction.z;
            t2 = max.z / direction.z;
            tMin = Math.Min(t1, t2);
            tMax = Math.Max(t1, t2);
            if (tMin > near) near = tMin;
            if (tMax < far) far = tMax;
            if (near > far || far < 0)
            {
                point1 = Vec3.zero;
                point2 = Vec3.zero;
                return false;
            }

            point1 = origin + direction * near;
            point2 = origin + direction * far;
            return true;
        }
}
```