# 3D line segment box intersection

Tags: python, 3d

Looking for code to detect an intersection between a 3D segment (not a line/ray) and a 3D box (not necessarily a cube, but always axis-aligned). The boxes are voxels so they have regular spacing.

Already have the code to find a segment/plane intersection. Ideally, I'd like to find an efficient solution to adapt this for a rectangle, repeat for each face of the 3d box, and then iterate for tens of thousands of segments and boxes.

```
seg_start = array([x1,y1,z1])
seg_end = array([x2,y2,z2])
plane_point = array([x3,y3,z3])
plane_normal = array([x4,y4,z4])
u = seg_end - seg_start
w = seg_start - plane_point
D = dot(plane_normal,u)
N = -dot(plane_normal,w)
sI = N / D
if sI >= 0 and sI <= 1:
    return 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you probably meant `and` rather than `or` in your if-condition, otherwise it'll just always return true. Second, if you're just testing whether there is an intersection or not, you can do it faster (without the float-division):

- You can determine which "side" of each plane any given point is on using vector math:
  `side = dot(my_point - plane_point, plane_normal)`
  Now if `side` is positive, `my_point` is "in front of" the plane (i.e. it's on the side the normal is pointing towards); if negative, it's "behind" the plane. If `side` is zero, your point lies on the plane.
- You can check whether your segment intersects an (infinite) plane by just testing to see if the start point and end point are on different sides:

  > ```
  > start_side = dot(seg_start - plane_point, plane_normal)
  > end_side = dot(seg_end - plane_point, plane_normal)
  > return start_side * end_side
  > #if < 0, both points lie on different sides, hence intersection
  > #if = 0, at least one point lies on the plane
  > #if > 0, both points lie on the same side, i.e. no intersection
  > ```
- You can use the "side" check to do the axis-aligned-cuboid intersection too (actually, this will work for any parallelpiped):

  - Treat your box as a set of six planes
  - Make sure the plane normals are all pointing either "outwards" or "inwards" from the box. I'll assume you're using "outwards"
  - For any point to lie inside your box, it has to be "behind" *all six planes*. If it isn't, it lies outside the box.
  - <strike>For any segment to intersect the box, one point has to lie outside it and one inside.</strike>
  - That's all!

**edit:** The last point is actually incorrect; as you say, voxels can be intersected even if both endpoints lie outside. So it's not the whole solution - actually, you can't really do this without calculating the intersection point. You can, however, still use the "side test" as an *early-reject* mechanism, so as to cut down on the number of full calculations you need to do: if both points are on the same side of *any one* of the six planes, there can be no intersection.

As far as your specific case goes, it seems like you're trying to find all intersecting voxels for some given line segment? In that case, you'd probably be better served using something like [Bresenham's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to explicitly calculate the path, instead of testing for intersections against all of the voxels...

Comment: Thanks - very helpful! What if the two points of the segment lie in voxels that are not adjacent and I want to test if the segment intersects the intermediate voxels (through which the segment passes, but for which both point will lie outside)?

Comment: @jbrown - yeah, I'd realized that too; I've amended my answer, take a look.

Comment: Side note for posterity: Bresenham's algorithm does not return every box a segment intersects. If the boxes form a voxel-like grid, a simple algorithm which samples evenly-spaced points along the 3D segment and returns the boxes it hits can be easily modified to return all boxes the segment intersects. Assuming dense-enough sampling, at each stride, there has to be a check of how many dimensions were incremented from the previous voxel. If 2 or 3 dimensions differ, potentially-missed voxels (offset by only 1 in one dimension from either previous or next voxel) can be checked explicitly.

Comment: P.S. here is an algorithm for explicit grid-aligned box checks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106666/intersection-of-line-segment-with-axis-aligned-box-in-c-sharp/59074742#59074742

Answer (score 1):

Just to have this archived with a sufficient background (the answers above seem to not include some collision cases):

[This question looks to be quite the same, with a good answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106666/intersection-of-line-segment-with-axis-aligned-box-in-c-sharp#3115514)

[In this thesis the problem is explained with pictures and descriptions on pages 15-19.](https://repositum.tuwien.at/handle/20.500.12708/3295)

[link went bad over time](http://www.garagegames.com/community/blogs/view/309)

Comment: The second link is sadly broken

Comment: I added another link from a university to a thesis describing the problem in detail. This should last longer, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Because the box is axis-aligned, all you need to do is to check for interval intersection in each coordinate.

Here is an example in python, with some tests. Note that it is generic for N dimensions, and it is the same algorithm for box-box intersection:

```
def are_intervals_intersecting(a0, a1, b0, b1):
    '''
    @param a0: float
    @param a1: float
    @param b0: float
    @param b1: float
    '''
    if (a1 < a0):
        a1, a0 = a0, a1

    if (b1 < b0):
        b1, b0 = b0, b1

    # 6 conditions:

    # 1)
    #        a0 ---------- a1                              a0 < b0 and a1 < b0
    #                             b0 ---------- b1         (no intersection)

    # 2)
    #               a0 ---------- a1
    #                      b0 ---------- b1                (intersection)

    # 3)
    #               a0 ------------------------ a1
    #                      b0 ---------- b1                (intersection)

    # 4)
    #                      a0 ---------- a1         
    #               b0 ------------------------ b1         (intersection)

    # 5)
    #                             a0 ---------- a1         (intersection)
    #                      b0 ---------- b1

    # 6)
    #                                    a0 ---------- a1  b0 < a0 and b1 < a0         
    #               b0 ---------- b1                       (no intersection)

    if b0 < a0:
        # conditions 4, 5 and 6
        return a0 < b1 # conditions 4 and 5
    else:
        # conditions 1, 2 and 3
        return b0 < a1 # conditions 2 and 3


def is_segment_intersecting_box(P0, P1, B0, B1):
    '''
    @param P0: tuple(float)
    @param P1: tuple(float)
    @param B0: tuple(float)
    @param B1: tuple(float)
    '''
    for i in xrange(len(P0)):
        if not are_intervals_intersecting(P0[i], P1[i], B0[i], B1[i]):
            return False
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert not is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

    assert not is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (4.0, 1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

    assert not is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (1.5, 1.5, 0.0), (4.0, 2.5, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

    assert is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (1.5, 1.5, 0.0), (4.0, 2.5, 2.5), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

    assert is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (1.5, 1.5, 1.5), (2.5, 2.5, 2.5), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

    assert is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (2.5, 2.5, 2.5), (2.6, 2.6, 2.6), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

    assert is_segment_intersecting_box(
        (2.5, 2.5), (2.5, 3.5), (2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0))

    print 'ok'
```

Comment: A simpler test for intervals would be (a0 < b1) and (b0 < a1).

Comment: -1. *Because the box is axis-aligned, all you need to do is to check for interval intersection in each coordinate.* This is wrong. Consider box `(0, 0), (2, 2)`. Segment `(-1, 2), (2, -1)` intersects it while segment `(-2, 1), (1, -2)` doesn't, but your code returns `True` for both.