# What is 3d vector with AABB Box intersection true/false detection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

Say we have a AABB ([Axis Aligned Bounding Box](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Axis-Aligned+Bounding+Box)) defined via 2 min/max vectors P, Q of form [x,y,z], and a vector R we try to intersect with it, of same form.  Origins of the vectors P, Q, and R are at the same point, [0,0,0]. How to detect whether R intersects AABB?  Result may be true or false – intersection points are not needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "Vectors [0,0,0] are in same point"? Do you want to check, if a point is within the AABB or if the coresponding line segment intersects with the AABB bounds? Btw, never use the same variable names for different things (x, y, z).

Comment: DuckQueen, I edited some stuff but  you will need to edit the question further and fix any misunderstanding I might have introduced

Comment: It is still unclear what the question is looking for.  The definition of the AABB, though awkward, seems clear enough, but is the intersecting "vector" supposed to be a point (the given location R), a segment (from the origin to the point R) or a ray (from the origin to infinity in the *direction* of R)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the intersection point between a line and a rectangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

Comment: @mbeckish: that's a 2D problem, this one is 3D.

Comment: @JWWalker - The idea is the same, you just need to look for 6 line segment / plane intersections rather than 4 line segment / line segment intersections.  Here's a 3D [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106666/21727).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What one normally wants to do is intersect a ray, not a vector, with an AABB.  I'm not sure what it would mean to intersect a vector with an AABB, maybe a finite section of a ray, in which case a ray-AABB algorithm would probably solve it for you.  See Andrew Woo's "Fast Ray-Box Intersection" in the book "Graphics Gems".  The [program code](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gems/RayBox.c) is available online.